# My Life Story- What Am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry, affix-riddle

Here's my life recap, just for fun-
I was a gangster at age one!

Hesitation soon surrounded me
And I was disgusting by age three.

I got between the rarest in the crust
And by five became anything I must.

Then into a large apple I would go
And by age seven tell my parents, “No!”

**What am I?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> you are "G" (slang for gangsta)

hesitation is

> is "UH" making  "UGH"

rarest element is

> "AT"  astatine  making  "AUGHT"

Big apple is

> "NY" making "NAUGHTY"